# Syntax error in Fish Shell path completion

Tags: fish, tab-completion

I made the mistake of putting an ampersand (&) in a directory name. I renamed the directory, but now every time I change directory it prints an error message:

```
complete: Completion '[A list of directories' path]' contained a syntax error. Expected an argument, but found a '&'
```

I don't know where those path completions are stored. I looked into the folders listed in the `$fish_complete_path` list without luck...

This problem should be easy to fix, only I don't know where to look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had fisherman installed. I uninstalled OMF, deleted fisherman files and plugins(I had z and get installed). Now it works. Not sure exactly which of those was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is because there is an `eval` somewhere that is evaluating a string that wasn't properly escaped. In this case it would be the __fish_complete_cd function. Which, in fish 2.2.0, did in fact use eval in an unsafe fashion. As of fish 2.3.0 it no longer does so which means you can safely use an ampersand in a directory name.

Normally I would recommend opening a bug report at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues with as much detail as possible including the version of fish you're running (`echo $FISH_VERSION`) and steps to reproduce the issue. However, in this case we've already fixed the bug so all you need to do is upgrade your fish installation. Until you can do so you should be able to "fix" the immediate problem by simply starting a new shell: `exec fish`.

Comment: I am using fish 2.3.1. Also, starting a new shell doesn't solve the problem(I have rebooted my computer a few times since). If this matters, I have OMF installed...

Comment: OMF ships a few completions that sometimes cause issues. I'd suggest removing OMF paths from $fish_complete_path to see if they're causing this.